# Does $\sup|A-B| \ge |\sup A -\sup B|$?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

I have strong intuition that "yes" is the answer, because the difference between any two points between $A$ and $B$ can be only bigger (or equal) to the difference between two specific points. But I couldn't prove it.
Would like to see a prove, or a counter example of course.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: If they are sets, which I assume they are, how do you even calculate $\left| A - B \right|$?

Comment: sup|A-B|  is well-defined also when A,B are sets, which they **can** be (or finite groups as the given example below) @AniruddhaDeshmukh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, and your intuition is correct.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and find $a \in A$ such that $\sup A - a < \varepsilon$.

For any $b \in B$ we have 
$$\sup|A-B| \ge |a-b| \ge a-b > (\sup A - \varepsilon) - \sup B \ge (\sup A - \sup B) - \varepsilon$$
since $b \le \sup B$. Now $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary so it follows $\sup|A-B| \ge \sup A - \sup B$.

The inequality  $\sup|A-B| \ge \sup B - \sup A$ follows by symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Find $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ to $\epsilon$-approximate $\sup A$ and $\sup B$.  Then $|a-b|$ will approximate $|\sup A-\sup B|$, where $\sup|A-B|\geq|a-b|$.  Now let $\epsilon\to 0$.

The reverse inequality does not hold like you had originally also wanted.  Let $A=\{-1,0\}$ and $B=\{0,1\}$ so that $\sup|A-B|=2$, whereas $\sup A=0$ and $\sup B=1$ so that $|\sup A-\sup B|=1$.